# Quarzt start time set

Tags: quartz-scheduler

I am using Quartz for performing some jobs, every thing is working perfect but problem is that
**I want to set time particular time to start quartz**

i want to run quartz every day at 6:00PM how to set this time, right now my quartz is running after every 5 seconds

I am using java, jsf and primefaces.

**===UPDATE===**

I used the expression that **elbraulio** suggested and it is ok. But Quartz cron is not working,

here was my previous code :

```
<schedule>
    <job>
        <name>AJob</name>
        <group>AGroup</group>
        <description>Print a welcome message</description>
        <job-class>com.mkyong.scheduler.SchedulerJob</job-class>
    </job>

    <trigger>
        <cron>
            <name>dummyTriggerName</name>
            <job-name>AJob</job-name>
            <job-group>AGroup</job-group>
            <!-- It will run every 5 seconds -->
            <cron-expression>0/30 * * * * ?</cron-expression>
        </cron>
    </trigger>
</schedule>
```

now i have changed it in this but not working.

```
<schedule>
    <job>
        <name>AJob</name>
        <group>AGroup</group>
        <description>Print a welcome message</description>
        <job-class>com.mkyong.scheduler.SchedulerJob</job-class>
    </job>

    <trigger>
        <cron>
            <name>dummyTriggerName</name>
            <job-name>AJob</job-name>
            <job-group>AGroup</job-group>
            <!-- It will run every 5 seconds -->
            <cron-expression>0 0 18 ? * * *</cron-expression>
        </cron>
    </trigger>
</schedule>
```

**is there any time zone problem?**

Comment: start it with cron

Comment: @Maurice Perry  how i am completely new to this would you please send example code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is **the expression you need** to run every day at 6:00PM

```
0 0 18 ? * * *
```

Also, you can use [this site](https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html) to **generate expressions easily**.

Comment: Thank you   this expression is correct but not running to my side do not know why